# angular-tree-component:Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)

Tags: javascript, angular-tree-component

i am using angular v10 and `"angular-tree-component": "^8.5.6"`.but getting build error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/angular-tree-component/dist/angular-tree-component.d.ts:25:23 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).

25     static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders;
```

Using in the application like this

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [TreeModule],
   exports: [TreeModule]
   })

export class SharedModule { }
```

anything i have to do modification?

Thanks.

Comment: now i am using angular-tree-component new version [circlon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@circlon/angular-tree-component) and no more error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of "angular-tree-component", use the new library "**@circlon/angular-tree-component**"

```
npm uninstall angular-tree-component
npm i @circlon/angular-tree-component
```

and then, update all imports in your project from:

```
import {TreeComponent} from 'angular-tree-component';
```

to:

```
import {TreeComponent} from '@circlon/angular-tree-component';
```

and css if needed from:

```
@import '~angular-tree-component/dist/angular-tree-component.css';
```

to

```
@import "~@circlon/angular-tree-component/css/angular-tree-component.css";
```